# Adding cruise control to BMW without electronic throttle control

Tags: bmw, cruise-control

I don't know very much about throttle bodies and stuff, but I do have an interesting question: I just bought a 2000 BMW 323i with the M52TU engine. It would seem that this specific year does not have electronic throttle control, so retrofitting cruise control to it would either be a complete overhaul of the system or completely impossible. (I'm not a car expert, so *please* correct me if I'm wrong here.)

My question is, does anyone know if it is possible to retrofit cruise control to this car? If so, what would it entail? If not, does anyone have a spare foot?

Jokes aside, any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

As you say, the M52 engine does not have an electronic throttle. However, the M52 was available with cruise control, so retrofitting the BMW system will be the neatest solution (as a bonus, you'll get audio controls on the steering wheel!).

BMW actually produced a standard kit for dealers to retrofitting cruise control, which makes your life easier. This thread should have all the info you need for your M52: http://forum.e46fanatics.com/showthread.php?t=618671

I've read some conflicting reports about whether a re-code of the ECU is required, but these instructions says it isn't, so fingers crossed...

Comment: I just ordered the MFSW and cruise control wiring harness, so we'll see! Wish me luck.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually choices for you out there. I'm not sure if these *exact* Universal Cruise Control units would work, but it should give you some ideas:

[Rostra Universal Electronic Cruise Control 250-1223](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007ZCQD9S)

Another possible option:

[Audiovox CCS100 Universal Vacuum Cruise Control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00029WQTW)

A buddy of mine installed one on his car (older Nissan) and it worked perfectly for what he wanted.

Comment: Neither one of those is compatible with BMW. They seem to do their own thing in this area.

Comment: I'm not sure why they would not be compatible? These are completely autonomous from the BMW systems. They attach to the throttle linkage. The only thing you need is a speed signal, which can be gained from the transmission or from an anti-lock brake wheel sensor, both of which I'm sure a 2000 BMW has.

Comment: Well, I'd also need a switch for the clutch wouldn't I? Also, what would it attach to if there's only room for one cable in the throttle body?

Comment: Sounds like you are giving up way too easily to me. You connect the cable *at* the throttle body. If I'm looking at the pictures correctly, your throttle body should be on the driver's side of the engine with the cable connection on the bottom side. There should be a knob sticking out from the wheel which the throttle cable is attached to. This should work as a point which you can attach the cruise control cable. You may have to finagle a few things, because it looks tight under the hood, but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at it and report back. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 0):

Belive me or not,
I installed on my e39 520i 97 m52b28 engine cruise control.
It took me really few days maybe about week- to sort out all items you need.
Cruise control UNIT,MFL sterring unit if your sterring wheel is before 07.97,cruise control acutator with linkage, power on button on dash(dependes), and few good meters of diffrent colour cables. If you lacky enough you get wires from scrap yard /if not plugs for them will be great.
I have an sterring wheel with heater element from 96 7series which doesnt have MFL control unit on it - so I had to do lots for wiring - BUT is possigle to make it working.

Then If you sort this out check for any problems via INPA remove all faults, and you need to code it - NCSEXPERT so the icon of CRUISE ON/Off will work on Instrument Cluster.

Good Luck!!
Marcin